# Endpoint when using AD FS SAML token with with SharePoint 2019

Tags: c#, sharepoint, saml, adfs, sharepoint-2019

I have fetched a SAML Token from AD FS for the Relying Party Trust I have set up with my local SharePoint server.

The the important part of the response from ADFS is given below.

Using this, I have been able to retrieve an access token from SharePoint by posting a **url-encoded-form** to `http://mylocalsharepoint/_trust/default.aspx` and grabbing the set-cookie - essentially emulating the action of the Login UI.

My question is, is there a better endpoint other than `http://mylocalsharepoint/_trust/default.aspx` (this is what the Login GUI page uses) as this is returning an entire web page but all I really need is the access token (fedAuth cookie) plus it requires a url-encoded-form -it would be great to be able to just use the XML SOAP message or at least XML.

I have found `/_vti_bin/authentication.asmx` but that seems to only support username and password mode.

I would really appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction. Thanks very much.

```
<trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
    <trust:Lifetime>
        <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2022-10-19T16:56:36.105Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2022-10-19T17:56:36.105Z</wsu:Expires>
    </trust:Lifetime>
    <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
        <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
            <wsa:Address>urn:sharepoint:spsites</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:EndpointReference>
    </wsp:AppliesTo>
    <trust:RequestedSecurityToken>
        <saml:Assertion MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" AssertionID="_3519cbe0-66fb-4bc3-9a40-91ea06cb0ad7" Issuer="http://ms-adfs.intranet/adfs/services/trust" IssueInstant="2022-10-19T16:56:36.230Z" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion">
            <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2022-10-19T16:56:36.105Z" NotOnOrAfter="2022-10-19T17:56:36.105Z">
                <saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
                    <saml:Audience>urn:sharepoint:spsites</saml:Audience>
                </saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
            </saml:Conditions>
            <saml:AttributeStatement>
                <saml:Subject>
                    <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                        <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
                    </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                </saml:Subject>
                <saml:Attribute AttributeName="emailaddress" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims">
                    <saml:AttributeValue>billbates@microsotofu.com</saml:AttributeValue>
                </saml:Attribute>
            </saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationMethod="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:am:X509-PKI" AuthenticationInstant="2022-10-19T16:56:35.639Z">
                <saml:Subject>
                    <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                        <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
                    </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                </saml:Subject>
            </saml:AuthenticationStatement>
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#_3519cbe0-66fb-4bc3-9a40-91ea06cb0ad7">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>gTz6J3z40UUkqOf1DV3gAe4yel5AD0GVPCJ7xI6ac44=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>ftyI5grqS01/g9zpfUuPn24xXMvJ...</ds:SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <X509Data>
                        <X509Certificate>MIICxDCCAaygAwIBAgIQEqN9pL4STbx...</X509Certificate>
                    </X509Data>
                </KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
        </saml:Assertion>
    </trust:RequestedSecurityToken>
    <trust:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</trust:TokenType>
    <trust:RequestType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Issue</trust:RequestType>
    <trust:KeyType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer</trust:KeyType>
</trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
```

Comment: I used this when I was configuring SAML authentication. [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](https://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html). 
OneLogin's Open-Source SAML Toolkits is a good reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to developing a C# customization as Farm Solution to include a custom endpoint to your SharePoint side like an ASHX prepared to receive the given XML contract above and redirect to this new custom endpoint, the C# code needs the minimal three things:

1. Guarantee security using CORS approach;
2. Deserialize the received XML from custom authentication provider;
3. And, the last one: developing custom Authorization into SharePoint side;

About the item 3, it's recommended this Microsoft Learn topic: [Create a claims provider in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-create-a-claims-provider-in-sharepoint)